# get rid of broadcom bcm4313 and use only a usb wifi adaptor ralink

Tags: wireless, broadcom

please someone help me, i want to disactivate totally broadcom and use my external usb adaptor tp-link, i uninstalled all broadcom drivers from additional drivers and synaptic and ubuntu store, aslo uninstalled the compat-wireless, but i still see it loading
please check more infos at pastebin :

http://pastebin.com/7eV3GivQ

thank you

solved by removing brcmsmac from the startup : sudo nano /etc/modules
thanks again

Comment: If @mikewhatever's answer helped you to fix the issue. Please go ahead and mark the answer as **accepted**

Answer (score 1):

You also need to blacklist `brcmsmac`,

```
echo 'blacklist brcmsmac' | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Comment: blacklisted it, as superuser in the terminal, rebooted, but still loading :        http://pastebin.com/57GVv013

Comment: should i blacklist these modules too : http://pastebin.com/SkEK0MSm   ?

Comment: should i blacklist these modules too : pastebin.com/SkEK0MSm                    tested and rebooted, no success still this brcmsmac everywhere

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to blacklist anything other then `brcmsmac`.

Comment: how i can remove it totally please ? by removing the directory of compat-wireless ?

Comment: You'll have to recompile the kernel. Blacklisting is the way to go, try backlisting `bcma` as well.

Comment: are you sure about recompiling the kernel ? if yes please how to do it, im a newb to ubuntu,  i blacklisted bcma and there is no changes after the reboot